# Display a network image when clicking a button

Tags: image, flutter, widget

i'm quite new with mobile development and with Flutter but it seemed like a good technology to try. So right now, I have an API, which sends photos and text when asked, but everytime you ask, it's a different one. So when i display these text in my app it works fine, when i press the intended button it makes the request again, so i get a new text phrase. But when i want to get an image, it works the first time, and then it seems like the request is not done again, the image stays the same. How could I make the request get made again when i press the button ? Feel free to ask every question you need, I paste my widget's code just below

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
        child: FutureBuilder(
      future: _loadImage(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Image> image) {
        if (image.hasData) {
          return image.data; // image is ready
        } else {
          return Text("No photo available"); // placeholder
        }
      },
    ));
  }

  Future<Image> _loadImage() async {
    
     return Image.network(
      'http://192.168.1.19:5000/photo',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':
            'Bearer token',
      },
    );
    
  }

}

Thanks in advance :)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1** - Add a random parameter to your request:

```
Future<Image> _loadImage() async {
  
  var nowParam = DateFormat('yyyyddMMHHmm').format(DateTime.now());

  return Image.network(
    'http://192.168.1.19:5000/photo#' + nowParam,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization':
        'Bearer token',
    },
  );

}
```

**Option 2** - Add a random key to your image and clear the cache on button click:

```
Future<Image> _loadImage() async {

  return Image.network(
    'http://192.168.1.19:5000/photo',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization':
        'Bearer token',
    },
    key: ValueKey(new Random().nextInt(100)),),
  );

}

...

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void buttonClick() {
  imageCache.clear();
  imageCache.clearLiveImages();
}
```

Comment: Thx, i'll try this rn :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)